# Using Titanium, Remove current view or pop current view

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have to remove current view being in the same view... 
if i am in the parent view i can do

```
parentView.remove(childView);
```

but being on the child view i am not having **parentView** so how can i pop **childView** to get **parentView** on top, as it happens on pressing the back button in iOS??
please help

Here is my childView file..

```
function DetailView(){


var self = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor:'#fff'
});
// Create a Button.
var aButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : 'aButton',
    height : '50',
    width : '100',
    top : '10',
    left : '20'
});

// Listen for click events.
aButton.addEventListener('click', function() {

     alert('\'aButton\' was clicked!');
```

***I have to navigate back on press of aButton, what should i Put here to do that***

```
});

// Add to the parent view.
self.add(aButton);


return(self);
 }
module.exports = DetailView;
```

Here is my parent view:

```
    //FirstView Component Constructor
    var self = Ti.UI.createView();

    function FirstView() {
//create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable


var DetailView = require('ui/common/DetailView');

var data = [{title:"Row 1"},{title:"Row 2"}];
var table = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    data:data
    });
table.addEventListener('click', rowSelected);

self.add(table);

return self;
    }

    function rowSelected()
    {
var DetailView = require('ui/common/DetailView');

//construct UI
var detailView = new DetailView();
self.add(detailView);

    }

    module.exports = FirstView;
```

Comment: You can hide the child view as well.

Comment: What you did you ask you wamt pop the child view to get the parent view on top what its means both are in top please forst clarify your question.

Comment: child view is on top of parent view.. and i have to remove child and navigate back to parent view as it happens on pressing the back button

Comment: ok then try with these four method that will help you out of your problem.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan but is hiding the right approach? will it be removed from the memory?

Comment: No it won't be removed from the memory, your question was not clear, but now you defined the real issue.

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpach How you add a child view to main view, please show that code as well.

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan please check.. i have added parentView code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass your parentView to the constructor of child view at this point:

```
//construct UI
var detailView = new DetailView(parentView);
self.add(detailView);
```

and in click event

```
aButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
   if ( parentView != null ) {
       parentView.remove(childView);
    }
});
```